# Convert Tree to List

Tags: list, f#, tree, type-conversion

everyone! I have a list type:

```
type ConsList<'value> =
    | Cons of head: 'value * tail: ConsList<'value>
    | Empty
```

And a tree type:

```
type Tree<'value> =
    | Node of value: 'value * children: ConsList<Tree<'value>>
    | Leaf of value: 'value
```

I would like a function that could collect all values in nodes and leaves of a Tree and convert them into a ConsList in order starting from the root and following from left to right.

For example, if I have: `Node(1, Cons(Leaf 2, Cons(Leaf 3, Empty)))`

Then I expect the output to be: `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Empty)))`

I have fold-functions, if they can be useful:

```
let rec fold folder acc lst =
    let f = fold folder

    match lst with
    | Empty -> acc
    | Cons (hd, tl) -> f (folder acc hd) tl

let rec fold folder acc tree =
    let f = fold folder

    match tree with
    | Leaf value -> folder acc value
    | Node(value, children) -> ConsList.fold f (folder acc value) children
```

Comment: is this homework? I don't want to help you cheat. So can i just give a hint. Imagine you had a loop that looped through all the nodes, and in each iteration you added an element to the list. The loop is called "fold", all you need to do is write the code inside the loop to add an element to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tree `fold` to build up a list of values. Something like this:

```ml
Tree.fold (fun currentStateOfList value ->
    // add value to currentStateOfList here
    ) initialStateOfList aTree
```

You need to figure out:

- What is the initial state of the list?
- What should be done to add a value to the current state of the list?

Depending on the requirements, you might also have to reverse the order of the list at the end.

Comment: It seems that the first is Empty, and the second is concatenation, but how to implement this does not occur to me.

I would also like to do without reversing.

Comment: Think about what `Cons` does. Can you use that to implement concatenation?

Comment: I think I'm at the finish line, it remains to learn to somehow add an item to the end of the list. Is it even possible?

Comment: Not with immutable lists, such as the one you're working with. However, it's not difficult to define a function called `rev` that reverses a list. You could give it a try. (I'm glad you worked out the solution. Nice work!)

Answer (score 0):

If I had an n-ary tree, it might "look" something like the following.

```
            ----1--------------------
           /          \              \
       ---2---      ---3----        --4--
      /  /    \    /  /  \  \      /     \
     5  6      7  8  9   10 11    12   --13--
                                      /      \
                                     14      15
```

My F# is not great, but I'm reasonably proficient in OCaml, so this type might look something like the following, if I don't define my own list type.

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a | Tree of 'a * 'a tree list
```

Creating the above structure is then:

```
Tree (1,
 [Tree (2, [Node 5; Node 6; Node 7]);
  Tree (3, [Node 8; Node 9; Node 10; Node 11]);
  Tree (4, [Node 12; Tree (13, [Node 14; Node 15])])])
```

To convert this to a list in a depth-first manner, and to preserve tail-recursion, a stack-based algorithm can be employed. As we iterate through, we keep a stack of `tree` values to evaluate in turn.

For the above example, we'd cons `1` onto a result list, then recursively call `tree_to_list` function on:

```
  ---2---
 /  /    \
5  6      7
```

While putting the remainder of the children on the stack.

```
  ---3----         --4--
 /  /  \  \       /     \
8  9   10 11     12   --13--
                     /      \
                    14      15
```

Encountering a `Node`, we'd cons the value onto the result list, and store the remaining trees (boths Nodes) on the stack.

```
6   7    ---3----         --4--
        /  /  \  \       /     \
       8  9   10 11     12   --13--
                            /      \
                           14      15
```

Now we begin consuming the stack. The `6` and `7` nodes go first, then we start with the `3` `Tree`.

```
9   10   11    --4--
              /     \
             12   --13--
                 /      \
                14      15
```

And then eventually consume the `4` `Tree` until we hit a `Node` or a `Tree` with no children (really the same thing) and the stack is empty. Then, because we've been building up the list backwards for efficiency, we need to reverse it.

A straightforward implementation might look like:

```ml
let tree_to_list t = 
  let rec tree_to_list' t a s =
    match t, s with
    | (Node v | Tree (v, [])), [] -> List.rev (v :: a)
    | Node v, x::xs -> tree_to_list' x (v :: a) xs
    | Tree (v, x::xs), _ -> tree_to_list' x (v :: a) (xs @ s)
    | Tree (v, []), s::ss -> tree_to_list' s (v :: a) ss
  in
  tree_to_list' t [] []
```

Given the close relation between the languages, hopefully you will find this algorithm readily applicable.